# IIS Server (PHP)$_GET or $_REQUEST shows empty URL String Query

Tags: php, iis, get, request, cgi

I'm trying to understand if this a bug or something I need to enable on my PHP server. When I enter in a string query in the URL like this:

```
www.website/test.php?f=123
```

and use a $_GET or $_REQUEST on my local machine I'm able to get the string query to display:

```
Array
(
    [f] => 123
)
```

However, on my live PHP server, I'm unable to use $_GET or $_REQUEST, it just shows an empty array. Using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` works and I have to put this code at the beginning of all my code:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $request);
```

To get the string query, but this seems like a temp solution until I understand why $_GET or $_REQUEST is unable to work.

The PHP server does not have rewrite modules/rules running under the IIS manager. I've tried to "Allow Query String" under the Default web site under IIS manager and restarted it, this didn't work either. If possible, can someone point me to what to look for or explain why $_GET/$_REQUEST doesn't work?

Comment: definitely something wrong with your PHP installation on your live server. how did you set it up? (eg, apache+mod_php ? apache+php-fpm? nginx+php-fpm? what?)

Comment: Check the [`variables_order`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) ini setting - you'd normally expect it to be set to something like **GPCS** (where G means populate the `$_GET` superglobal), but potentially it could have been changed.

Comment: *"The PHP server API is CGI/FastCGI which appears to not have a .htaccess file anywhere. I've tried to "Allow Query String" under the Default web site under IIS manager*" ... if it's an IIS server, `.htaccess` is irrelevant - if it's an Apache server, the IIS manager is irrelevant... which is it?

Comment: @hanshenrik it was installed before I got here, so I'm not sure (relatively new to PHP setups).  Checking the phpinfo() it shows it is running version 7.1.5 with the "Server API" listed as CGI/Fast CGI. I use the Inetpub folder /IIS to access the PHP files.  On my local machine, I'm using WAMP with Apache.

Comment: @iainn the 
; variables_order;   Default Value: "EGPCS" and I tried to change it to GPCS and restarted the App pools but no luck

Comment: @CD001 it's using IIS server, sorry I'm still new to PHP

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in IIS windows server and I solved deleting is attribute in th web.config file

`appendQueryString="false"`

fine this line :

`<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />`

and remove the attribute above